# Script to pull from POEditor timeout on Bitrise

Tags: android, bitrise

Currently I have an automatic build pipeline to build android apk on Bitrise, one of the step before build is pulling translated language from POEditor. Previously, the build has run successfully until on around 30 May it starts to fail. The failure is because of a timeout when 'curl' to POEditor API.

The Bitrise stack I used is Android&Docker Ubuntu 14.04, the staff has stated it is hosted on Google Compute Engine. I have another pipeline to build ios app which pull from POEditor also, and it still working without problem until now.

The POEditor API is to export the language (https://api.poeditor.com/v2/projects/export).

Answer (score 0):

As we stated in our private chat there was absolutely no change on the related infrastructure; the last time we changed anything port/network related was about half a year ago and even then we enabled a new port and that's all.

One thing you might want to try is to switch from the Ubuntu 14 stack to the Ubuntu 16 one, although the 14 one did not change for quite a while and should work, but this might worth a try.

You can also try to run `curl` with the `--versbose` or other flag to get more info about the issue. If you can provide more debug infos feel free to contact us any time!

Comment: Hello Viktor, I have tried to switch the stack to Ubuntu 16, and it failed also. While when I change to OSX stack it successfully connecting to POEditor. But it is not an option for me as some script and step in my pipeline is not available in those stack.
Btw now it has work again, I don't know whats the problem, my guess is theres change in GCE or POEditor
Notes: I've contact POEditor staff, but they haven't reply yet

Comment: @fchristysen if you'd get a response from them please let us know!